# Supabase RealTime Channel Swift

Tags: swift, supabase

I am using supabase for one of my Swift projects. While I was using a free module from supabase, it was working perfectly. Now I have deployed it in our local development server. After deploying to local server, it is not listening to the insert, update, delete from the tables of supabase while the queries are working fine. I have connected to realtime client properly and also subscribing to the channels properly.

Please note that out local server is on HTTP while the module from Supabase is on HTTPS. Will it make any issue??

I have also enabled Allow Arbitrary Loads from Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

It worked in local server after turning off the Row Level Security from Supabase